# Are questions regarding SaaS providers, such as email fulfillment on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, there are a number of email fulfillment SaaS applications (ExactTarget, Silverpop, ConstantContact, Mailchimp - the list goes on and on)

Are specific questions regarding these services, as web applications, welcome here?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why they are off topic, since they *behave like a web application*. Feel free to ask questions about them, though the question should still be specific about the **usage** of the web application.

Comment: I think they're on topic, but by their nature we're not going to have a lot of expertise here to answer questions about them.

Comment: Yes, that is true. This applies to all the other unanswered questions as well - we simply do not have enough experts on those areas...